# iPhone - Syncing objects to server with sqlite3

Tags: iphone, sqlite, information-retrieval

Hey.  I'm looking for best practices on how to sync information stored in my sqlite db on the iphone with my main server.

To give more information, the iPhone app stores books a user is reading and allows them to browse the books in a list form.  All the information about the book is stored on a server and is editable from a website.  So when the user starts the app I need to sync the sqlite db on the phone with my main server to get the current list of books.

Anyone have suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to deal with the "Changes" and not the whole book list every time the app is launched. So the first time, you'd download everything (or seed the iphone with some initial data), then keep track of the updates.

Then on subsequent launches, kick off an NSThread (in applicationDidFinishLaunch:) to download the changes to the book list, since some timestamp, to the iPhone. Parse the data, update your db, record a new timestamp, then reload your UITableView or whatever View, you're using.

If you're going to allow editing on the iphone you have additional concurrency issues (e.g. editing the same book at the same time).

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable